# drupal ctools multi step node form

Tags: ajax, drupal, modal-dialog, drupal-ctools

I've built a ctools modal form with multi step [like this](http://internetdevels.com/blog/ctools-multistep-wizard-example),
and I've built a ctools modal node form [like this](https://gist.github.com/mrconnerton/1979037).

Cool! but now I want a ctools multi-step modal node form. Yes, I could render all the fields via Form API, hang all the validation & custom widgets and then write my own submit handler, but why bother when the node form would do that for me already?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The trick was to load the node into the $form_state as an argument, then there are a couple ways you can render the form (see below).

```
ctools_include('node.pages', 'node', '');
$form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
$output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('my_content_type_node_form', $form_state);
print ajax_render($output);

ctools_include('node.pages', 'node', '');
$form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
$form = drupal_retrieve_form('my_content_type_node_form', &$form_state);
print ajax_render($output);
```

My reason for wanting this was to avoid having to re-include all the submission handlers & validation that the node form already possesses. However due to the ajax, if you have a file upload in your form, you'll also need this:

```
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```